# Task not serializable: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String$IntWrapper

Tags: scala, apache-spark, wrapper

I am currently working on migrating a hive table.  The problem I am facing is, when I try to load it into a dataframe in spark and write back to the Hive, it gives me a serialization error like in the screen shot attached. However, when I try to perform a Dataframe transformation with ~60 columns, it works fine. We have approximately 200 columns that we need out of the 1800 columns in the table. I think it’s because of size of the table that’s causing that error.

I think the serialization error is caused by “Spark version 2.2.0” (being used in our dev clusters). There is a bug related to “org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String$IntWrapper” that causes this error in this version. In spark versions 2.2.1 and higher this bug was resolved as per the issue report.  As a turn around to this I tried to wrap the jar that I deployed, with the updated dependencies. I still face the same issue because I think it is still using the default jars from the dev environment. I would be very thankful if there is any alternative to run it.

Link to the apache bug= https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21445

Link to the solution = https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/18660/commits/d2202903518b3dfa0f4a719a0b9cb5431088ed66

In the solution to the problem they wrote the code in java, I am writing mine in scala. I want to know how to import "IntWrapper" and "LongWrapper" classes from UTF8String library and let the program use my declared variables. For this I have written classes taking the class in the link as reference and using KryoRegistrator in spark to call those classes to my "spark session". Is this correct?
bsTst3.scala

```
    import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
    import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
    import org.apache.spark.sql.Column
    import org.apache.spark.sql.sources.IsNotNull
    import org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer
    import org.apache.spark.SerializableWritable
    import java.io._

    @SerialVersionUID(0L)
    class IntWrapper extends  Serializable{
      @transient var value:Int=0 
    }

    @SerialVersionUID(1L)  
    class LongWrapper extends  Serializable{
      @transient var value:Long=0 

    }

    object bsTst3 {
      def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

        val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("DrfApp")
                     .config("spark.kryo.registrator", "bsKryoRegistrator")
                    .config("spark.kryoserializer.buffer", "1024k")
                    .config("spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max", "1024m") 
                    .enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
        val bDRF = spark.sql("select * from global.table_partition1 limit 10")                

        import spark.implicits._

        bDRF.write.saveAsTable("katukuri.sample3")

      }
    }
```

and this is scala class is what i'm calling from the main object
bsKryoRegistrator.scala

```
    import org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoRegistrator
    import com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo;
    import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable

    class bsKryoRegistrator extends KryoRegistrator {

      override def registerClasses(kryo: Kryo) {
        kryo.register(classOf[Byte])
        kryo.register(classOf[Short])
        //kryo.register(classOf[Int])
        //kryo.register(classOf[Long])
        kryo.register(classOf[IntWrapper])
        kryo.register(classOf[LongWrapper])
        kryo.register(classOf[Float])
        kryo.register(classOf[Double])
        kryo.register(classOf[String])
        kryo.register(classOf[Boolean])
        kryo.register(classOf[Char])
        kryo.register(classOf[Null])
        kryo.register(classOf[Nothing])
        //kryo.register(classOf[None])
        kryo.register(classOf[NullWritable])
      }

    }
```

command that i use to run it on my dev cluster

```
spark2-submit --class bsTst3 --master yarn --queue root.default  --deploy-mode client BSDrdTest3-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

error i get, which is similar to the one in the link to the bug

```
    19/02/27 18:06:14 INFO spark.SparkContext: Starting job: saveAsTable at bsTst3.scala:37
19/02/27 18:06:14 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Registering RDD 6 (saveAsTable at bsTst3.scala:37)
19/02/27 18:06:14 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Got job 0 (saveAsTable at bsTst3.scala:37) with 1 output partitions
19/02/27 18:06:14 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 1 (saveAsTable at bsTst3.scala:37)
19/02/27 18:06:14 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List(ShuffleMapStage 0)
19/02/27 18:06:14 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List(ShuffleMapStage 0)
19/02/27 18:06:14 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Submitting ShuffleMapStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[6] at saveAsTable at bsTst3.scala:37), which has no missing parents
19/02/27 18:06:14 INFO cluster.YarnScheduler: Cancelling stage 0
19/02/27 18:06:14 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: ShuffleMapStage 0 (saveAsTable at bsTst3.scala:37) failed in Unknown s due to Job aborted due to stage failure: Task not serializable: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String$IntWrapper
Serialization stack:
        - object not serializable (class: org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String$IntWrapper, value: org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String$IntWrapper@63ec9c06)
        - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Cast$$anonfun$castToInt$1, name: result$2, type: class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String$IntWrapper)
```